# Drawing a rectangle that fits the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

If a quad's coordinates are defined as:

```
(-1,-1,0)  (-1,1,0)  
( 1,-1,0)  ( 1,1,0)
```

and use:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 100.0f);      
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

what scale values or `glLookAt` values or whatever values would be needed to make the square appear to precisely cover a rectangular viewing area (no more, no less)? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be perspective projection? It would be a lot easier to drop gluPerspective and gluLookAt and just use an orthographic matrix:

I'd replace both lines with just

`glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your response, you mean that this is not satisfactory, because other objects in your frame need perspective rendering?

If that's the case, note that you can switch projection modes anytime during the scene, so you can render your quad with orthographic projection and render the rest of the scene with perspective with no problem.

If you really do want to render it in perspective mode, you'll need to do trigonometry to calculate the lookat dimensions. But I don't know why you'd want to do this.